# aerospike installed using vagrant is not working properly

Tags: aerospike

I'm trying to install aerospike in my local by following the steps [here](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/vagrant/mac).

```
mkdir ~/aerospike-vm && cd ~/aerospike-vm
vagrant init aerospike/aerospike-ce
vagrant up
```

All the above commands are successful and there are no error.

Below is the minimal log of the `vagrant up` command.

```
default: Successfully added box 'aerospike/aerospike-ce' (v4.5.0.5) for 'virtualbox'!
.
.
.
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 5.2.12
    default: VirtualBox Version: 6.0
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/aerospike-vm
```

Below command clearly show only amc is running but not aerospike.

```
BOSM0001-RANATA:aerospike-vm rajkumar.natarajan$ vagrant ssh -c "sudo service aerospike status"
asd is stopped
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

BOSM0001-RANATA:aerospike-vm rajkumar.natarajan$ vagrant ssh -c "sudo service amc status"
amc (pid  1458) is running...
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.


BOSM0001-RANATA:aerospike-vm rajkumar.natarajan$ vagrant ssh -c "sudo grep -i cake /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log"
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

Any idea what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do: `$ vagrant ssh` 
that will get you inside the shell. Then see why aerospike did not start.
First try:

```
$ sudo service aerospike start
```

then

```
$ sudo service aerospike status
```

If it is not running, go through `/var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log` and see what the log file is showing as the error.